# How to read properties of JSON response in postman?

Tags: javascript, postman

I would like to read property names from response json and compare. example my json is line below,

```
var response = 
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "tester",
      "id": "123"
    }
  ],
  "includes": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "id": "345"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check response.data[0] has the properties name and id. For this I tried to read property name like below,

```
var first = response.data[0];
var firstProperty = first[0]; //I expected like it will return [ "name"]. but its returning as undefined.
```

`Note - to make it clear, I want to read the property name from json [name, id]. not the property value [tester, 123]`

could someone help me please?

Comment: Well, the name field would be either `response.data[0].name` or `response.includes[0].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `object.keys()`.

```
var first = response.data[0];
var firstProperty = Object.keys(object)[0]
```

`Object.keys(myObj)` returns an array with the keys. You can subset the first index, ie. "name" from this array.

Read more here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: string first=response.data;
       foreach  (var row in first)
       {
              Console.WriteLine(row.name);
              Console.WriteLine(row.id);
        }

Comment: You can display name,id as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to create a test to check the keys, you could create one and include an assertion like this:

`pm.expect(response.data[0]).to.include.all.keys('name', 'id');`